# How to add and use a resource in C99 project with CMake that is portable?

Tags: cmake, embedded-resource, c99, clion, portability

I am trying to create a CMake C99 project that will have an embedded resource that can be read by the project. And this project should be portable. I am actually using CLion but I think this is a just CMake question.

Ideally I would like to see a simply way to embed `helloworld.txt` file in the CMake project and then a way to read the contents into `const char* helloword_txt = ??` variable. And then have this compile with GCC or a Microsoft C++ compiler.

I have looked at the `CMakeRC.cmake` project but that look like a C++ specific way. I looked at commands like `ld -r -b binary -o binary.o foo.bar  # then link in binary.o` but that look like Linux-specific way.

I thought CMake was designed for portable projects. Is there a portable way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a independent resource management system available. At least, I don't know of any.

You can take a look at Qt's qrc - it is more or less portable, but introduce a Qt dependency, of course.

Comment: Qt is C++ so probably a good choice for some but not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First I would use [`FILE *fopen( const char *restrict filename, const char *restrict mode )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) from C99 Standard.

Then in CMake I would use [`install(FILES helloworld.txt DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-files)
note: `CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR` comes from [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) built-in module.

Then using a bash/bat script you can always run the program from the "BIN_DIR" so the path to helloworld.txt is "."

e.g. `add_executable(foo_prg ...)` ... `install(TARGETS foo_prg ...)`
/usr/bin/foo:

```sh
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  cd /usr/bin && ./foo_prg
```

So user can run `./foo` which will "trampoline" to `/usr/bin` to run `foo_prg` binary

Note: To test without installing, you can add to CMake:

```
file(COPY helloworld.txt DESTINATION ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
```

note: does not work for multi-configuration build but should be easy to deduce.
note2: don't know (i.e. never tested) if we can use `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo_prg,RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>` instead.

Comment: Does this strategy embed the resource in the executable?